# Problema ao estilizar <select> através de CSS

Tags: html, css

Olá!

Montei um formulário para captação de leads, e não estou conseguindo estilizar o campo  dentro do mesmo. Já pesquisei bastante e tentei de tudo, mas não estou conseguindo entender porque não está funcionando.

A página é a seguinte: https://superalitoral.com.br/teste/

Código do formulário:

```
<form id="formulario" action="" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" id="unidade" name="unidade" value="281">
    <input type="hidden" id="chave" name="chave" value="739164197">
<div width="100%">
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="campos" placeholder="Seu nome" required>
</div>
<div width="100%">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="campos" placeholder="Seu e-mail" required>
<div width="100%">
    <input type="tel" id="telefone" name="telefone" class="campos" placeholder="Seu celular" required>
</div>    
<div width="100%" class="motivo">
    <select id ="observacoes" name="observacoes">
    <option value="Opção 1">Opção 1</option>
    <option value="Opção 2">Opção 2</option>
    <option value="Opção 3">Opção 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div width="100%" align="center">
    <button onClick="form()" id="enviar" name="enviar" type="submit" class="btn-enviar">Enviar</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Class "motivo":

```
.motivo select {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
    font-family: "Nunito Sans";
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: -0.5px;
    background-color: #ECDAB2;
    color: #C55300;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Já tentei incluir "!important" após as linhas, mas aparentemente não funciona. Além disso, exclui todas referências ao select que tinha no css original do tema.

Fora isso, não estou entendendo porque está aparecendo um text input na seleção - gostaria de deixar fechado entre as opções que eu vou disponibilizar.

Alguém tem um palpite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto não é um SELECT customizado, é um elemento alternativo SIMULADO, não é o SELECT de verdade que esta ali, é uma série de elementos em um plugin que simulam o SELECT, o select original esta oculto, não adianta aplicar CSS, o plugin usado é este https://select2.org/ ele transformou isto:

```
<div width="100%" class="motivo">
    <select id ="observacoes" name="observacoes">
    <option value="Opção 1">Opção 1</option>
    <option value="Opção 2">Opção 2</option>
    <option value="Opção 3">Opção 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Nisto (dinamicamente):

```
<div width="100%" class="motivo" data-select2-id="4"> <select id="observacoes" name="observacoes" placeholder="Selecione um motivo..." data-select2-id="observacoes" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true"><option value="Opção 1" data-select2-id="2">Opção 1</option><option value="Opção 2" data-select2-id="5">Opção 2</option><option value="Opção 3" data-select2-id="6">Opção 3</option> </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="1" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-observacoes-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-observacoes-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Opção 1">Opção 1</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span></div>
```

Veja que foi aplicado `class=select2-hidden-accessible` ocultando o SELECT original

Basta remover o tal select2 da página e todas suas referencias em scripts que deve resolver

Comment: Obrigado, Guilherme! Era isso mesmo!